# preg_match for postcodes and locations

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to extract two pieces of information from a location.

An example location would be: 
Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020

Where I'm trying to extract "Sorrento" and "6020".

"Hocking Parade" is a street that I don't need, which will always be followed by a comma. "WA" is a constant. The post code is 4 digits.

EDIT: Should clarify the date is actually in the format:
`<span>Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020</span>`

Works:
`preg_match('/^.*, (.*) [A-Z]{2} (\d{4})$/','Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020',$uTitle);`

Doesn't work:
`preg_match('/^.*, (.*) [A-Z]{2} (\d{4})$/','<span>Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020</span>',$uTitle);`

Comment: Why don't you at least show us a first attempt at doing this?

Comment: Well, if the format is always the same, that's too easy for an answer: /^.*, (.*) [A-Z]{2} (\d{4})$/

Comment: I have never used expressions properly. This was my attempt:
`preg_match('%, (.*?) WA ([0-9]){4}%i','Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020',$uTitle);`

Comment: Your example worked on the example I gave, but it didn't when I put it into use because the dates are actually in a span like so:
`<span>Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020</span>`

Comment: I updated my answer to cover also the `span` requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$address= "Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020";
preg_match_all(', (.*?) WA (\d{4})/i', $address, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$city = $result[1][0];
$zip = $result[2][0];
```

cheers,

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I copied and pasted, but the only solution that seems to work so far is above:
`/^.*, (.*) [A-Z]{2} (\d{4})$/` but it doesn't properly because I have <spans>

Comment: hi there,I've tested it with the example you've provided and it works, not sure if the copy/paste messed with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$str = "<span>Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020</span>";
preg_match('/,\s+(.*)\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+(\d{4})/', $str, $m);
echo $m[1]; // prints Sorrento
echo $m[2]; // prints 6020
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?
$target = '<span>Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020</span>';

preg_match("/.+?,\s+([^\s]+).+?([^<]+)/", $target, $matched); 
echo '<pre>'; print_r($matched); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hocking Parade, Sorrento WA 6020
    [1] => Sorrento
    [2] => WA 6020
)
```